# Build failed with an exception Initialization script 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\ho_main__.gradle' line: 41

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, build.gradle

can any one tell me how to solve this error

i am facing this issue

Initialization script 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\ho_main__.gradle' line: 41

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not create task ':app:ho.main()'.
> SourceSet with name 'main' not found.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/8.0/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 631ms

ok_main_gradle

```
def gradlePath = ':app'
def runAppTaskName = 'ok.main()'
def mainClass = 'com.example.basic1.ok'
def javaExePath = mapPath('F:/Andriod/jbr/bin/java.exe')
def _workingDir = mapPath('D:/Basic1')

def sourceSetName = 'main'
def javaModuleName = null





import org.gradle.util.GradleVersion

allprojects {
  afterEvaluate { project ->
    if(project.path == gradlePath && project?.convention?.findPlugin(JavaPluginConvention)) {
      def overwrite = project.tasks.findByName(runAppTaskName) != null
      project.tasks.create(name: runAppTaskName, overwrite: overwrite, type: JavaExec) {
        if (javaExePath) executable = javaExePath
        main = mainClass
        
        if (_workingDir) workingDir = _workingDir
        standardInput = System.in
        if (javaModuleName) {
          classpath = tasks[sourceSets[sourceSetName].jarTaskName].outputs.files + project.sourceSets[sourceSetName].runtimeClasspath;
          if (GradleVersion.current().baseVersion < GradleVersion.version("6.4")) {
            doFirst {
              jvmArgs += [
                '--module-path', classpath.asPath,
                '--module', javaModuleName + '/' + mainClass
              ]
              classpath = files()
            }
          } else {
            mainModule = javaModuleName
          }
        } else {
          classpath = project.sourceSets[sourceSetName].runtimeClasspath
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: share gradle file content in question

Comment: hello sir i have add gradle file code